# mvc 6 IApplicationEnvironment causes blank page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp 5 mvc 6 project and I just added IApplicationEnvironment to a controller and all of a sudden going to any action in that controller returns a blank screen, a 500 error I can see in the development tools

```
readonly DBDataContext _dbcontext;
readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnv;

public ContactController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv, DBDataContext dbcontext)
{
    _dbcontext = dbcontext;
    _appEnv = appEnv;
}
```

does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it was because I had
`Microsoft.Framework.Runtime`
instead of
`using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;`
at the top of the controller. Using the second one made it work fine.